# Eclipse IDE design problems

Tags: eclipse, windows-8, eclipse-juno

I got a few problems with my eclipse. I hope, that you can give me some advice.
I like dark themes, so I found [Eclipse Color Themes plugin](http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/), which is cool, but it did darker only the editor window, but I want to have full dark theme. Not only edit view. What this depends on? (My os is Windows 8)

[Illustrative screen](http://prntscr.com/uxd2m)

second think is to setup the toolbars. I was trying to hide some features, which I did never use (f.e. "Quick Access"). So I open Window->Customize Perspective, uncheck what I don't want to and tap ok. But nothing happend. I tried to restart eclipse, but still without change. When I open Customize Perspective window, there is everything still checked. And this will happend again and again. Any ideas?

[Illustrative screen 2](http://prntscr.com/uxd7l)

I apologize for my english :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple, just dont use eclipse.